# Pygame using TKinter to make a popup menu?

Tags: python

I need to  have a pygame window  check if the user right clicked (I can do) and then make a popup menu to display options using TKinter (?). Is this possible?

Comment: It may be possible, but it's probably easier to keep everything within PyGame.

Answer (score 0):

Import tkinter as you would usually do so, and create your popup.  It would be best to stay within pygame though, using tkinter and pygame would end up being pretty complicated.